# How can I increase/decrease (frequency/pitch) of signal

Tags: matlab, octave, fft

How can I increase/decrease (frequency/pitch) and phase using fft/ifft I think I have the basic code but I’m not sure what to do next

I was told repmat and resample may help, yes I want to linear shift all components. I want to adjust the phase over time so that it will create a standing wave. One signal with the phase changing in one direction and another signal with the phase going the opposite direction

PS:  It's done in Octave/matlab code

Example I have a signal that's repeats 1 time every second and I want to have it repeat 3 times a second instead.

```
%Voiceprint raise lower freq phase conjugate signal
tic
clear all, clc,clf,tic
%% Sound /beep calculation complete
filerawbeepStr='calculations_complete.wav';
filerawbeeppathStr='/home/rat/Documents/octave/raw/';
filevoiceprepathStr='/home/rat/Documents/octave/eq_research/main/transform/voice/';
filewavpathStr='/home/rat/Documents/octave/eq_research/main/transform/wav/';
[ybeep, Fsbeep, nbitsbeep] = wavread(strcat(filerawbeeppathStr,filerawbeepStr));
%addpath(”/home/rat/Documents/octave/eq_research/main/transform/”); %add path to location of functions

%1a voice print import
[vp_sig_orig, fs_rate, nbitsraw] = wavread(strcat(filevoiceprepathStr,'voice8000fs.wav')); 

%vp_sig_orig=vp_sig_orig’;
vp_sig_len=length(vp_sig_orig);

%2a create frequency domain
ya_fft = fft(vp_sig_orig);
vp_sig_phase_orig = unwrap(angle(ya_fft));

%get Magnitude
ya_fft_mag = abs(ya_fft);

%3a frequency back to time domain
ya_ifft=real(ifft(ya_fft));

%adjust frequency/phase here? How?
vp_sig_new=real(ifft(ya_fft_mag.*exp(i*vp_sig_phase_orig)));

subplot(3,1,1), plot(vp_sig_orig),title('1 original time domain')
subplot(3,1,2), plot(ya_ifft),title('2 rebuild time domain')
subplot(3,1,3), plot(vp_sig_new),title('3 adjusted time')
```

Comment: *How* do you want to modify the frequency of each component, exactly ? Fixed (i.e. linear) shift of all components ? Scaling of all components by constant factor (i.e. log shifting) ? And what exactly do you want to do with the phase (and why) ?

Comment: @Paul R I was told repmat and resample may help, yes linear shift of all components. I want to adjust the phase over time so that it will create a standing wave.  One signal with the phase changing in one direction and another signal with the phase going the opposite direction

Comment: OK - you should probably edit your question to include this information - then it will be clearer as to what it is that you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do this but if the signal is large you may have to increase the number of points to the signal

```
clear,clc
fs = 44100;                   % Sampling frequency
t=linspace(0,1,fs);
freq=1;
ya = sin(2*pi*freq*t)'; %+ 1*sin(2*pi*250*t); 


num_per_sec=5
yb=repmat(ya,num_per_sec,1);%replicate matrix 
xxo=linspace(0,1,length(yb))'; %go from 0 to 1 sec can change speed by incr/decr 1
xxi=linspace(0,1,length(ya))'; %go from 0 to 1 sec and get total samplerate from total y value
yi_t=interp1(xxo,yb,xxi,'linear');

plot(yi_t)
```